# SessionID generating muliple times for single request in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, sessionid

Generally in asp.net we have unique sessionID for one request,

**Example** : Once you browse any website, during this entire browsing activity from one browser is considered as one Session, and it should only carry **one** Session ID

But here for my website for ONE Request Many SessionID's are creating in fraction of Seconds its 25000 within 1 day.. !

Can any one explain me some concept of how to control this generation of **SessionIDs multiple times**??

Answer (score 0):

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx)

When using cookie-based session state, ASP.NET does not allocate storage for session data until the Session object is used. As a result, a new session ID is generated for each page request until the session object is accessed. If your application requires a static session ID for the entire session, you can either implement the Session_Start method in the application's Global.asax file and store data in the Session object to fix the session ID, or you can use code in another part of your application to explicitly store data in the Session object.

If your application uses cookieless session state, the session ID is generated on the first page view and is maintained for the entire session.

Comment: Will try and get back.., Thanks

Comment: Iam doing it in Session_Start method in Global.asax file and doing same as you suggested. But still iam getting the same multiple SessionIDs